# how to retrieve values from csv file within specific period using R

Tags: r

let say i have dataset for State , year , week and location in csv format
i want retrieve all data for specific state for year 2014 from week 36 to week 53 as follow

i've already do this but still have another not need states, thnx

```
LH14 <- (function(){
 x <- read.csv("LocationHotspot2014.csv")
 x[,"State"] <- toupper(lh14[,"State"])
 x[x$State=="California",],
 x[x$Week== c(36:53) ,] 
 })()
```

Comment: You will need `%in%` insteed of `==` for checking whther the weeks match.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several errors. This should run, assuming the csv file exists and has the appropriate columns.

```
LH14 <- function() { 
  x <- read.csv("LocationHotspot2014.csv")
  x$State <- toupper(x$State)
  x <- x[x$State == "CALIFORNIA" & x$Week %in% 36:53, ]
  x
}
lh14 <- LH14()
```

edit: Replaced `subset` with indexing per Roman's suggestion.

Comment: FWIW, for non-interactive use, `subset` is not recommended.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I've not heard that before, why is that?

Comment: See `?subset`: "This is a convenience function intended for use interactively. For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting functions like [, and in particular the non-standard evaluation of argument subset can have unanticipated consequences."

Comment: Thank you guys 
 Josh u r right  its work now   thnaks